# How to change the database store point instead of this link, the data should store to my localhost

Tags: ionic3

I just copy this code from code from [setup-login-register-ionic3-using-php-mysql](https://ionicdon.com/setup-login-register-ionic3-using-php-mysql/?unapproved=6226&moderation-hash=40109fbea56e53ddf7b4fb4f654031ff#comment-6226]) he created a localhost database from phpMyAdmin but then I was wondering why my data is not storing in my localhost even though I was able to authenticate a user account.

Then I found out that the store point is going through that link in post ('').

How can I change that store point to my localhost?

```
loader.present().then(() => {
    this.http.post('http://ionicdon.com/mobile/register.php', data, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        loader.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming that you are using WAMP or XAMP server for local testing, you need to put all the PHP files inside www/project_name or htdocs/project_name folder respectively.

Then request the page from the ionic app to your local server like this:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/mobile/register.php',data, options)
```

**If you want to test your ionic app on your device or emulator**, you need to follow these steps:

1. Connect your local server(PC or Laptop) and your smartphone to the same network(Genreally same Wifi).
2. Put your WAMP/XAMMP server online and allow local connections. Reference: https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/
3. Run ipconfig command on Windows and ifconfig on Linux/Mac to get your local address
4. Replace the address in http post request to your local IP address

   this.http.post('http://192.168.1.7/mobile/register.php',data, options)
5. Now, you can test your ionic app on your device

Comment: hi sir im having this situation in my /mobile/register.php

'require "dbconnect.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if (isset($data)) {

        $request = json_decode($data);
**line 38        $emailadd = $request->email;**
**line 39        $password = $request->password;**
**line 40        $username = $request->username;**
**line 41        $mobile = $request->mobile;**

                                }'

Comment: '$username = stripslashes($username);

$password = stripslashes($password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, telephone)

**line 51       VALUES ('$name', '$password', '$emailadd', '$mobile')";**

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

                $response= "Registration successfull";

} else {

**line 48      $response= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;**

}

 echo json_encode( $response);
'

says: 
**Error: INSERT INTO users (name, password, email, telephone)\r\n\r\nVALUES ('', '', '', '')**'

Comment: @MjSaijem I am glad that my post provided you the answer. If you have an error in PHP, you need to post another question with the PHP tag on StackOverflow and provide your full code and error that you are getting. Happy to help :)